# Cannot connected to virutal IP loadbalancer direct to mysql server

Tags: mysql, load-balancing, wordpress, high-availability, mysql-replication

I can't connect to the Database server though virtual IP

https://towardsdatascience.com/high-availability-mysql-cluster-with-load-balancing-using-haproxy-and-heartbeat-40a16e134691

I follow this guide, but when my web server trying to connect to it, it fail

`sudo mysql -u wordpress -h 192.168.122.98 -p`

`Enter password:`

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'wordpress'@'db1' (using password: YES)`

My virutal IP for that interfaces is: 192.168.122.98

My IP for database is: 192.168.122.187

I can connect directly to the database:

`sudo mysql -u wordpress -h 192.168.122.187 -p`
`Enter password:`
`Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.`
`Your MySQL connection id is 1724`
`Server version: 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log (Ubuntu)`

`Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights` reserved.`

`Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its`
`affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective`
`owners.`

`Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input` `statement.`

`quan@db1:~$ ip addr show ens3`

`2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast`

stateUP group default qlen 1000`

`link/ether 52:54:00:a1:83:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`

```
`inet 192.168.122.187/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global ens3`

  ` valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`
```

`inet 192.168.122.98/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global secondary` 
`ens3:0`
       `valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

```
`inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fea1:83fb/64 scope link `

   `valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your Web Server IP to DB:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'wordpress'@'YourWebServerIP' IDENTIFIED BY 'YourPassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```